# IAuthorizationMiddlewareHandler not checking roles

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly

I have the following code in the server app of a blazor wasm application

```
public class BlazorAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler:IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler
{
    public Task HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
    {
            return next(context);
    }
}
```

This is to get around an annoying bug in Blazors authentication in .net 8. It works fine when a plain [Authorize] attribute is on the class, however when we add a role [Authorize(Roles="test")], it ignores the role and allows the user to hit the methods.

The "AuthorizationPolicy" parameter of the HandleAsync Method contains the following in Requirements.

> {RolesAuthorizationRequirement:User.IsInRole must be true for one of
> the following roles: (test)}

How do I get it to check against this role and reject the request if it the user is not in the role?

Answer (score 0):

To check the roles requirement ,it should be

```
private readonly AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler defaultHandler = new();

public async Task HandleAsync(
    RequestDelegate next,
    HttpContext context,
    AuthorizationPolicy policy,
    PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
{

    await defaultHandler.HandleAsync(next, context, policy, authorizeResult);
}
```

Reference :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/customizingauthorizationmiddlewareresponse?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Comment: Unfortunately this results in the same bug that I put the Handler in to fix in the first place... (It throws a 401 if you go to a page directly from a url or if you refresh the page)

Comment: @coolblue2000 `return next(context);`  bypass all the authorize.  So when you bypass the backend, font-end authorize still work? But it still doesn't work for roles?

Comment: The client side blazor does authorize fine along with roles. But it uses the standard ,net process. The server side does not work as there is a bug in .net 8. (This is EntraID B2B by the way). So we have had to put in the above code to get around the bug, it works for normal auth but it does not check the roles.